# Access chart switch from date to category on the x-axis

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a chart that is trying to show dates in the x-axis.  I really need it to be a category and show text labels instead.  I can't figure out a way to switch in Access 2007.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is to trick access into thinking that the values are not dates.  You can convert to strings, add special formatting, or just an extra space like Jan  15, 2015.  Two spaces between Jan and 15.  Then it will automatically switch from Date to Category.